# TMUX Theame on WSL Broken - Only appearing on status bar

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to setup TMUX on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) for the first time and am having the issue that my installed theam only take effect on the status bar at the bottom. My `.tmux.conf` is below along with a screenshot.

I have tried adding

```
set -g default-terminal 'tmux-256color'
set -as terminal-overrides ',xterm*:Tc:sitm=\E[3m'
```

Among other things to no avail. And have made sure to `<C-b>I` as well as `tmux kill-server` between attempts.

```
# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'odedlaz/tmux-onedark-theme'
# Other examples:
# set -g @plugin 'github_username/plugin_name'
# set -g @plugin 'github_username/plugin_name#branch'
# set -g @plugin 'git@github.com:user/plugin'
# set -g @plugin 'git@bitbucket.com:user/plugin'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

[image: Screenshot showing status being the only working part]

Comment: I have fixed this by simply copying the theme colours by hand from the plugin